Several packages not installed in RShiny with Docker
I create a Dockerfile:
# Base image https://hub.docker.com/u/rocker/
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

# system libraries of general use
## install debian packages
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
    libxml2-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libsqlite3-dev \
    libmariadbd-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev \
    unixodbc-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libproj-dev \
    gdal-bin 

## update system libraries
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get clean

RUN install2.r --error \
    methods \
    jsonlite \
    tseries
    

RUN R -e "install.packages(pkgs=c('shiny','leaflet','leaflet.providers','ggplot2','dplyr','shinythemes','ggspatial','googleCloudStorageR','sf','lubridate','googleAuthR','blastula','shinymanager','tiff','raster','scales','sp','RColorBrewer','anytime','rmarkdown','knitr','zip','evaluate','highr','methods','markdown','stringr','yaml','xfun','formatR','testit','digest','rgl','codetools','htmlwidgets','webshot','tikzDevice','tinytex','reticulate','JuliaCall','magick','png','jpeg','gifski','xml2','showtext','tibble','sass','bslib','tidyverse','bigrquery','DBI','glue','geojsonR','fst'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/',force=TRUE,dependencies=TRUE)" 

RUN mkdir /root/app

COPY R /root/shiny_save

EXPOSE 8080

# RUN dos2unix /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh && apt-get --purge remove -y dos2unix && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/root/shiny_save', host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)"]unApp('/root/shiny_save', host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)"]


But when I run inside Docker, several packages are not installed. Like:

Please, why did this occur? Despite the install package specifications, and all the packages are found in cran:
RUN R -e "install.packages(pkgs=c('shiny','leaflet','leaflet.providers','ggplot2','dplyr','shinythemes','ggspatial','googleCloudStorageR','sf','lubridate','googleAuthR','blastula','shinymanager','tiff','raster','scales','sp','RColorBrewer','anytime','rmarkdown','knitr','zip','evaluate','highr','methods','markdown','stringr','yaml','xfun','formatR','testit','digest','rgl','codetools','htmlwidgets','webshot','tikzDevice','tinytex','reticulate','JuliaCall','magick','png','jpeg','gifski','xml2','showtext','tibble','sass','bslib','tidyverse','bigrquery','DBI','glue','geojsonR','fst'), repos='https://cran.rstudio.com/', force=TRUE)"

My app directory (R) is:

Thanks in advance!

do you call library(sf) explicitly in your code?

Yes, I called but it doesn't work.

{sf} has GDAL as a dependency, so you need to add libgdal-dev to your system dependencies.
It's worth noting that install.packages fails silently when you create a docker image which is why you're not getting any errors until you try to run it. Per Install R packages using docker file you can use install2.R instead which returns an error if installation fails:
RUN install2.r --error \
    methods \
    jsonlite \
    tseries


I'm sorry, but it hasn't been solved yet. I changed the Dockerfile (see above) to install GDAL, and the error remains.

Sorry my example was just copying from the other answer - methods, jsonlite, tseries should be replaced with the libraries to install (and then remove the install.packages)

And also gdal-bin is not the same as libgdal-dev
